# Duplicate entry 'asdfg@mail.ru' for key 'users_i.mail' в чём дело?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Форма для регистрации, в БД поле имя и е-майл задал как уникальные. Уходит с ошибкой Duplicate entry 'asdfg@mail.ru' for key 'users_i.mail'. Как обойти это сообщение и показать юзеру, что такая запись уже есть в БД?

```html
<form action="" method="POST" class="register-form" id="register-form">
       
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                                <input type="username" name="full_name" id="name" pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]{5,15}" title="Только латинские буквы. Длина строки ниже 5 или свыше 15 символов" placeholder="Логин от 5 до 15 символов" required <?php if (!empty($_POST['full_name'])) {
                                                                                                                echo "value=\"" . $_POST["full_name"] . "\"";
                                                                                                            } ?> />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ваша почта" required <?php if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
                                                                                                            echo "value=\"" . $_POST["email"] . "\"";
                                                                                                        } ?> />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Пароль" required <?php if (!empty($_POST['pass'])) {
                                                                                                        echo "value=\"" . $_POST["pass"] . "\"";
                                                                                                    } ?> />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="re-pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock-outline"></i></label>
                                <input type="password" name="re_pass" id="re_pass" placeholder="Повторите пароль" required <?php if (!empty($_POST['re_pass'])) {
                                                                                                                        echo "value=\"" . $_POST["re_pass"] . "\"";
                                                                                                                    } ?> />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="number"><i class="zmdi zmdi-phone"></i></label>
                                <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон №" required <?php if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) {
                                                                                                                        echo "value=\"" . $_POST["phone"] . "\"";
                                                                                                                    } ?> />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="agree-term" id="agree-term" class="agree-term" value="yes" />

                              <!--  <label for="agree-term" class="label-agree-term"><span><span></span></span>Я, принимаю все условия <a href="blocks/terms.php">
                                        <p>Условие и обслуживание</p>
                                    </a></label>-->

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-button">
                                <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" class="form-submit" value="Регистрация" />
                            </div>
                            
                        </form>
```

файл для БД

```html
<?php
// VAR input
$name = $_POST['full_name'];
$em = $_POST['email'];
$pas = $_POST['pass'];
$re_pass = $_POST['re_pass'];
$phon = $_POST['phone'];
$s = 0;
//if ($pas == '' || $name == '' || $em == '' ||$phon == 0) {
//echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Ошибка, поля пустые!');</script>");
//} else {
    $pas = password_hash($pas, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    
    //$pas = md5($pas + $salt);
    // Create connection
    require_once("blocks/testmysql.php");
    // insert informations       
    //echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>alert($phon);</script>");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users_i (log_name, email, pass, date_1, telefon, summa_t, dt, kt) VALUES ('$name', '$em', '$pas', NOW(), '+$phon', '$s', '$s', '$s')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
//}
?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта.

Первый, интуитивный:

1. select из бд пользователя по уникальному имейлу
2. если пользователь нашёлся, сообщить об ошибке: имейл занят
3. иначе insert в бд нового

Тут ошибка Duplicate entry всё ещё может возникнуть, если кто-то попробует зарегистрироваться с таким имейлом одновременно с первым пользователем. В обычном случае это очень редкое явление и можно на это забить.

Второй, более строгий:

1. insert в бд
2. [поймать исключение](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php)
3. если это Duplicate entry, сообщить об ошибке: имейл занят

Comment: Привет! Да, именно это и нужно мне. А вот как реализовать в код, вот это меня мучает. :(( Строго не судите всего пару месяцев пробую проект изменить. Чужой код сделать лучше. Поймать исключение из сообщения с БД для меня это впервой.

Comment: Ещё можно insert ignore и посмотреть affected rows, если 0 -- имейл уже занят.

Comment: @AlisherAhmedov если ООП и исключения пока для вас сложны, то воспользуйтесь первым способом. Он тоже хороший.

Comment: С первым вариантом почему-то код плохо ловит ошибки, пришлось многое изменить в коде. Даже в инпут поставил рекуэри, чтобы поля не были пустыми.

Comment: Использовал первый способ, вроде работает. Отправил на тест.

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу с первым вариантом предложенный Егор Банинном. Проверку сделал с помощью запроса в БД, конечно это будет не таким уж хорошим вариантом, если учесть частое обращение в БД.

```html
 // Проверка логина и е-майл адреса клиента
    $row1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users_i` WHERE `email`='$em'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $row2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users_i` WHERE `log_name`='$name'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($row1);
    $row1 = $row1['email'] ?? null;
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($row2);
    $row2 = $row2['log_name'] ?? null;
    if (strcmp($row2, $name) == 0) {
        echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>alert('логин существуют!');</script>");
    }
    elseif (strcmp($row1, $em) == 0) {
        echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>alert('е-майл существуют!');</script>");
    } else {
```

Вот кусок кода.